# Create JSON object in Swift with incompatible types

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a Swift dictionary to a JSON object using `JSONSerialization`
This works fine unless there is no incompatible type in the dictionary (like NSData)

Unfortunately the dictionaries are quite large and are generated by an other application that potentially will add `NSData` values the line below will cause an exception

```
JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: inputDictionary, options: [.prettyPrinted])
```

> Invalid type in JSON write (__NSCFData)

Is there a way to just ignore incompatible types instead of throwing an exception?
This way all data that is compatible will be in the JSON object and incompatible types will just be ignored.

Of course an option would be iterating through the dictionary before trying to convert it to JSON, but as these dictionaries are quite complex, I'm wondering if there is an easier way

Comment: Are you looking for [`isValidJSONObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1418461-isvalidjsonobject)?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I know that the data is not a valid JSON object but only because of these incompatible types which I need to be just ignored